# How to open a site by pushing a button

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to open Wikipedia site by pushing a button so I created this action:

```
@IBAction func wikiTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let urlW = URL[string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(place.name)"]

    if urlW != nil {
        let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(url: urlW)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)

    }
}
```

But it is not working. What did I do wrong? How I can adjust it?

Comment: It's `URL(string:)`, not `URL[string:]`.

Comment: "not working" is a useless statement. Please [edit] your question to include specific details about in what way exactly it isn't working.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, is not working because urlW is always nil, but this is impossible

Comment: Clearly it's not impossible because it is nil. You have spaces and/or other special characters in `place.name`. They need to be properly escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, try to be more specific when you ask your question. The `let urlW ...` line in your code gives you a nice big red error in Xcode.

This is also a good place to use `guard let` so you get rid of your if, and your code reads a bit cleaner:

```
guard let urlW = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(place.name)") else { return }
let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(url: urlW)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
```

Comment: This fixes the crash but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @fisherM Why did you accept this answer? It doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: There's no information to suggest `place.name` has characters not suited for an URL @rmaddy? But I agree that it's something @fisherM should be aware of: make sure you verify that this variable is formatted for use in an URL to make this work all of the time.

Comment: `urlW` is `nil`. That alone clearly indicates that `place.name` has characters that are not valid in a URL.

Comment: I guess I took that with a grain of salt since the original code was not even building as presented.

Comment: This answer only corrects his way of creating an NSURL with string, not giving a solution

Answer (score 1):

Next time when asking a question, please include the steps to reproduce and a brief description of the issue; that way it’s highly recommended to get a short and a quick answer,

## How do I use it? ##

According to your needs, to initialize `SFSafariViewController` when the user taps a button:

The `SFSafariViewController` API is delightfully simple. To create a `SFSafariViewController` just pass in a URL:

```
let bookmark = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!
let safari = SFSafariViewController(URL: bookmark)
presentViewController(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And note that SFSafariViewController needs to be presented, not pushed from a navigationController

> Pushing SFSafariViewController may result in a black screen or a nasty crash, it’s not even recommended to use it that way.

——

To open `SFSafariViewController` with Reader open use the full designated initializer:

```
let safari = SFSafariViewController(URL: bookmark, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
```

——

When `SFSafariViewController` is presented it appears fullscreen with a ‘Done’ button at the top right. However, tapping this button does nothing unless the `SFSafariViewController` instance has a delegate. The `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` protocol offers three optional methods. To respond to the ‘Done’ button a delegate must implement `safariViewControllerDidFinish`:

```
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

While this method is technically optional, an app that does not dismiss the view controller when the user taps done might feel broken to the user. Next is `safariViewController:didCompleteInitialLoad:`. This method lets the delegate know that loading has completed and indicates whether or not that load was successful.

```
func safariViewController(controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
    if didLoadSuccessfully == false {
        print("Page did not load!")
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```